# sqlite nested command are extremely slow (like 30 second)

Tags: sqlite

I try to get some complecated results using this command:

```
select ClientId, ClientName,ClientLastName,Client_Address,ClientCity, 
ClientPhone,ClientMail,
GROUP_CONCAT('[id:' || EID || '] [' ||  HDT || ']  ' ||  ECMT, '

') as Comments,LastCallDate, LastTalpan, LastCallResults,NextTimeToCall, 
ClientStatus
from (  

select DISTINCT CLIENT.ID as ClientId, 
 CLIENT.NAME as ClientName
 ,CLIENT.LAST_NAME as ClientLastName
 ,CLIENT.ADDRESS as Client_Address
 ,CLIENT.CITY as ClientCity
 , CLIENT.STATUS as ClientStatus
 ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  PHONE_NUMBERS.PHONE_NUMBER) as ClientPhone
 ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  MAIL.EMAIL) as ClientMail,  
 EVENT.ID as EID, 
 HISTORY.DATE as HDT, 
 EVENT.COMMENTS as ECMT,
 CALL_LATER.WANTED_NEXT_CALL as NextTimeToCall,
 SHIPPING_COMMANTS.SHIPPING_COMMANTS as HANCHAIA,
 SUBSCRIBE_RELATED.MORE_TO_SHEEP as MORE_TO_SHEEP,
 SUBSCRIBE_RELATED.TOKEF as TOKEF,
 TALPAN_RELATED_DATA.LAST_CALL_DATE as LastCallDate,
 TALPAN_RELATED_DATA.LAST_TALPAN as LastTalpan,
 TALPAN_RELATED_DATA.CALL_RESULTS as LastCallResults

from CLIENT

left join PHONE_NUMBERS on ClientId = PHONE_NUMBERS.CLIENT_ID AND 
PHONE_NUMBERS.PHONE_STATUS=1
left join MAIL on ClientId = MAIL.CLIENT_ID AND MAIL.MAIL_STATUS=1
left join TAGS  on ClientId = TAGS.CLIENT_ID  
left join HISTORY  on HISTORY.CLIENT_ID=CLIENT.ID AND HISTORY.ACTIVE=1
left join EVENT  on HISTORY.EVENT_ID= EVENT.ID
left join CALL_LATER  on CALL_LATER.CLIENT_ID= ClientId
left join SHIPPING_COMMANTS  on SHIPPING_COMMANTS.CLIENT_ID= ClientId AND 
SHIPPING_COMMANTS.ACTIVE=1
left join SUBSCRIBE_RELATED  on SUBSCRIBE_RELATED.CLIENT_ID= ClientId 
left join TALPAN_RELATED_DATA on TALPAN_RELATED_DATA.CLIENT_ID= ClientId
where  TAGS.TAG_NAME = 'TEST_TAG'
AND CLIENT.STATUS = 'CALL_LATER'
AND CLIENT.ALLOCATED = 0
GROUP BY ClientId
order by EID DESC)
GROUP BY ClientId;
```

I have multiple tables that ID from table CLIENT is the connector of them

table constract:

- CLIENT:
  "ID"
  "NAME"
  "LAST_NAME"
  "ADDRESS"
  "CITY"
  "STATUS"
  "ALLOCATED"
- PHONE_NUMBERS:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "PHONE_NUMBER"
  "COMMANTS"
  "PHONE_STATUS"
- EVENT:
  "ID"
  "EVENT_NAME"
  "COMMENTS"
- history:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "EVENT_ID"
  "DATE"
  "ACTIVE"
- CALL_LATER:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "TALPAN_MADE_LAST_CALL"
  "WANTED_NEXT_CALL"
  "ACTIVE"
- SHIPPING_COMMANTS:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "SHIPPING_COMMANTS"
  "ACTIVE"
- SUBSCRIBE_RELATED:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "MORE_TO_SHEEP"
  "TOKEF"
- TALPAN_RELATED_DATA:
  "ID"
  "CLIENT_ID"
  "LAST_CALL_DATE"
  "LAST_TALPAN"
  "CALL_RESULTS"

I want to get all the comments (events comments) that related to specific client_id and sort it backward (i.e. LIFO).

This command working but it's extremely slow (can take more then 40 sec. to execute and get results).

I'am sure that I do something rung here and this is why it's take so much time,I really appreciated points on my mistakes and examples of better commands that achieve the same results faster.

My query plan:

```
selectid | order | from | 
"1" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE CLIENT USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_CLIENT_1"
"1" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE PHONE_NUMBERS USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (PHONE_STATUS=? AND CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "2" "2" "SEARCH TABLE MAIL USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (MAIL_STATUS=? AND CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "3" "3" "SEARCH TABLE TAGS USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (TAG_NAME=? AND CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "4" "4" "SEARCH TABLE HISTORY USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (ACTIVE=?)"
"1" "5" "5" "SEARCH TABLE EVENT USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)"
"1" "6" "6" "SEARCH TABLE CALL_LATER USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "7" "7" "SEARCH TABLE SHIPPING_COMMANTS USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_SHIPPING_COMMANTS_1 (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "8" "8" "SCAN TABLE SUBSCRIBE_RELATED"
"1" "9" "9" "SEARCH TABLE TALPAN_RELATED_DATA USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT"
"1" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN SUBQUERY 1"
"0" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY"
```

My full code to create schema schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `CALL_LATER` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `TALPAN_MADE_LAST_CALL` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `WANTED_NEXT_CALL`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ACTIVE`    INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `CLIENT` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `NAME`  TEXT,
    `LAST_NAME` TEXT,
    `ADDRESS`   TEXT,
    `CITY`  TEXT,
    `STATUS`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ALLOCATED` INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `EVENT` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `EVENT_NAME`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `COMMENTS`  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `HISTORY` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `CLIENT_ID` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `EVENT_ID`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `DATE`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ACTIVE`    INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `MAIL` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `EMAIL` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `MAIL_STATUS`   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `PHONE_NUMBERS` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `PHONE_NUMBER`  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `COMMANTS`  TEXT,
    `PHONE_STATUS`  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `SHIPPING_COMMANTS` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `SHIPPING_COMMANTS` TEXT,
    `ACTIVE`    INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `SUBSCRIBE_RELATED` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `MORE_TO_SHEEP` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `TOKEF` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `TAGS` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `TAG_NAME`  TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `TALPAN_RELATED_DATA` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `LAST_CALL_DATE`    TEXT,
    `LAST_TALPAN`   TEXT,
    `CALL_RESULTS`  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `TALPAN_RELATED_DATA` (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `CLIENT_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `LAST_CALL_DATE`    TEXT,
    `LAST_TALPAN`   TEXT,
    `CALL_RESULTS`  TEXT
);
```

I added this indexes:

```
create index where_client_index1 ON CLIENT(STATUS,ALLOCATED)
create index where_client_index2 ON CLIENT(ID,STATUS,ALLOCATED)
CREATE INDEX where_phone1 on PHONE_NUMBERS(CLIENT_ID,PHONE_STATUS)
CREATE INDEX where_mail1 on MAIL(CLIENT_ID,MAIL_STATUS)
CREATE INDEX where_history1 on HISTORY(CLIENT_ID,ACTIVE)
CREATE INDEX tags_basic on TAGS(TAG_NAME)
create index phone_1 ON PHONE_NUMBERS(CLIENT_ID,PHONE_STATUS);
CREATE INDEX history2 on HISTORY(ACTIVE)
CREATE INDEX history1 on HISTORY(CLIENT_ID,ACTIVE)
CREATE INDEX CALL1 on CALL_LATER(CLIENT_ID)
CREATE INDEX TALPAN_RELATED_1 on TALPAN_RELATED_DATA(CLIENT_ID)
```

This is my new plan:

```
    "1" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE CLIENT USING INDEX where_client_index1 (STATUS=? AND ALLOCATED=?)"
"1" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE PHONE_NUMBERS USING INDEX phone_1 (CLIENT_ID=? AND PHONE_STATUS=?)"
"1" "2" "2" "SEARCH TABLE MAIL USING INDEX where_mail1 (CLIENT_ID=? AND MAIL_STATUS=?)"
"1" "3" "3" "SEARCH TABLE TAGS USING INDEX tags_basic (TAG_NAME=?)"
"1" "4" "4" "SEARCH TABLE HISTORY USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (ACTIVE=?)"
"1" "5" "5" "SEARCH TABLE EVENT USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)"
"1" "6" "6" "SEARCH TABLE CALL_LATER USING INDEX CALL1 (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "7" "7" "SEARCH TABLE SHIPPING_COMMANTS USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_SHIPPING_COMMANTS_1 (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "8" "8" "SCAN TABLE SUBSCRIBE_RELATED"
"1" "9" "9" "SEARCH TABLE TALPAN_RELATED_DATA USING INDEX TALPAN_RELATED_1 (CLIENT_ID=?)"
"1" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT"
"1" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN SUBQUERY 1"
"0" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY"
```

And still it's takes A LOT of time to exeutes.

----------- What I will try ----------------------
I think I will unite multiple tables to one and reduce by this 
segnifintly the use of joins

history:
id,client_id,event_name,commant,date,active
contect (unite phone+mail):
id,client_id,number,mail,number_active,mail_active
client (unite all the rest of the tables)

It's this a good plan?
I wander if it will save enagh time on every search...

Comment: You should start by researching how to optimize a query using things such as indices.

Comment: What's your query plan? https://sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: You should also show your actual table definitions (And indexes), not just lists of column names. `.schema` in the sqlite3 shell program is an easy way to get them.

Comment: @Shawn I added the code for schema and the plan

Comment: You have no indexes on most of the join columns. No wonder it's taking a long time; it's building a bunch of temporary ones (The AUTOMATIC indexes in the query plan) every time you execute that thing.

Comment: @Shawn I added indexes and new plan.

Comment: Since sqlite uses nested loop style joins, the more tables in a join, the inherently slower it is, so you're fighting an uphill battle. Some other things to try: Now that you've built indexes, run a `PRAGMA optimize` to generate some stats the query planner can use. Consider if you *really* need left joins or if inner joins will work for at least some of them. Get rid of the `ORDER BY` or move it to the outermost `SELECT`. Do you really need a `DISTINCT` (Related to trying to eliminate left joins).

Comment: @Shawn are there any trick I can do to get all data from multiple tables with lower overhead? I cant run commands that takes 40 s. to run...

Comment: @Shawn I add some solution I think t do , I would love for your opinion on this